# Linked ComboBoxes

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I am trying to make linked `ComboBoxes`. For example, I have three comboboxes and each of them have three items (a, b, c). In the beggining at the first combobox "a" is selected, in the second "b", and "c" in the third. I need to make such `ActionListener` for them, that works in this way: if change selection in the second list from "b" to "a", in the first list selected item automatically changes from "a" to "b".

I tried to solve the problem in that way:

```
 public class MyComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while (a.getSource() != valsListArray.get(i)) {
                i++;
            }
            String selected = valsListArray.get(i).getSelectedItem().toString();
            while (selected != valsListArray.get(j).getSelectedItem() && j != i) {
                j++;
            }
            String r = chosenVals[i];// in the beginnig elements are that order a, b, c
            valsListArray.get(j).setSelectedItem(chosenVals[i]);
            chosenVals[j] = r;
            chosenVals[i] = selected;
        }
    }
```

but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: This seems like an odd and unusual custom component - quite possibly unusable as well.  It seems a `JList` with Drag'n'Drop might be the better way to go about it.  What exactly are a, b & c?  What is the significance of the 'mutually exclusive' combos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yours is an interesting problem. One solution is to extend JComboBox such that it will hold a reference to its previously selected item and index, and this would allow you to extract the information when needed. For example:

```
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class NewComboBox extends JComboBox {
   private Object previousSelectedItem = null;
   private int previousSelectedIndex = -1;

   public Object getPreviousSelectedItem() {
      return previousSelectedItem;
   }

   public int getPreviousSelectedIndex() {
      return previousSelectedIndex;
   }

   NewComboBox(ComboBoxModel aModel) {
      super(aModel);
   }

   @Override
   public void setSelectedIndex(int anIndex) {
      previousSelectedIndex = getSelectedIndex();
      previousSelectedItem = getSelectedItem();
      super.setSelectedIndex(anIndex);
   }

   @Override
   public void setSelectedItem(Object anObject) {
      previousSelectedIndex = getSelectedIndex();
      previousSelectedItem = getSelectedItem();
      super.setSelectedItem(anObject);
   }

}
```

And then you could use it as needed. For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LinkedCombos extends JPanel {
   public static final String[] DATA = {"a", "b", "c"};
   public static final int COMBO_COUNT = 3;
   private DefaultComboBoxModel[] comboModels = new DefaultComboBoxModel[COMBO_COUNT];
   private NewComboBox[] comboBoxes = new NewComboBox[COMBO_COUNT];
   private MyComboListener myComboListener = new MyComboListener();

   public LinkedCombos() {
      for (int i = 0; i < comboModels.length; i++) {
         comboModels[i] = new DefaultComboBoxModel(DATA);
         comboBoxes[i] = new NewComboBox(comboModels[i]);
         comboBoxes[i].setSelectedIndex(i);
         comboBoxes[i].addActionListener(myComboListener);
         add(comboBoxes[i]);
      }
   }

   private class MyComboListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         NewComboBox combo = (NewComboBox) evt.getSource();
         String selection = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();

         for (int i = 0; i < comboBoxes.length; i++) {
            NewComboBox comboI = comboBoxes[i];
            if (comboI != combo && comboI.getSelectedItem().equals(selection)) {
               comboI.setSelectedItem(combo.getPreviousSelectedItem());
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      LinkedCombos mainPanel = new LinkedCombos();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LinkedCombos");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: agreed with your comment in the answer, EDIT ..., interesting code +100

Answer (score 6):

for example (only two linked JComboBoxes, rest is/are up to you, I'm removed code for 3rd. JCombobox intentionally)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComboBox mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox subComboBox;
    private Hashtable<Object, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

    public ComboBoxTwo() {
        String[] items = {"Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit"};
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
        mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        //prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        //mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        getContentPane().add(mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        subComboBox = new JComboBox();//  Create sub combo box with multiple models
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        subComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(subComboBox, BorderLayout.EAST);
        String[] subItems1 = {"Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);
        String[] subItems2 = {"Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle"};
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);
        String[] subItems3 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
//      mainComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String item = (String) mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get(item);
        if (o == null) {
            subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
        } else {
            subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if (e.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
                if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
                    FirstDialog firstDialog = new FirstDialog(ComboBoxTwo.this,
                            mainComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Please wait,  Searching for ..... ");
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    private class FirstDialog extends JDialog {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        FirstDialog(final Frame parent, String winTitle, String msgString) {
            super(parent, winTitle);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(msgString);
            JButton bNext = new JButton("Stop Processes");
            add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(bNext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            bNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            t.setRepeats(false);
            t.start();
            setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
            setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxTwo();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant some another problem, but thanks, it still useful for me.